# how to download all attachments in sharepoint website

Tags: 2013, document, download

I am upgrading WSS3.0 to sharepoint foundation 2013 so I need to get the attachments from WSS3.0 and import to new site. Is it possible to import all attachments?

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if I understood your question, I m assuming that you want to be sure that your attachments in WSS 3.0 will still be available once you upgrade to SharePoint 2013

In the upgrade process, your lists, list items, list attachments and every single file inside your WSS 3.0 will be upgraded and will be available in the newer version. There is no need after your migration to copy your attachments from the old lists and import to the new one.

And remember, you can`t (without a third part software tool) skip the upgrade to 2010. You must first upgrade from wss to 2010 and then you can go to 2013.

For additional information about upgrading, you may check the following links

Migration from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Server 2010: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/010c9de5-15c5-4e36-be01-43860e696eb4/migration-from-wss-30-to-sharepoint-server-2010

SharePoint 2013 Upgrade Step by Step From SharePoint 2010: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-step-by-step-from-sharepoint-2010/